# How to expand the shared location URL from Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps

I am trying to get the location from google map shared location link so I am using Google Shorten URL API to expand the URL but when I shared URL from Google Map application from the android device it gives me `https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3` this kind of URL. It does not give me actual expanded URL to provide Location information.

**how to expand this:**

`https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3`

**In this link:**

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Siddique+Trade+Center/@31.5313297,74.3504459,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x391904e4af9b1e35:0xee6f3c848c9e5341!8m2!3d31.5313297!4d74.3526346
```

Here is the **API URL** which I am using to expand it.

"`https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3&key=(API_KEY)`"

But instead of giving me the above location information URL it returns me this **Long URL**.

```
https://maps.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.google.com/maps/place//data%3D!4m2!3m1!1s0x391904e4af9b1e35:0xee6f3c848c9e5341?utm_source%3Dmstt_1&apn=com.google.android.apps.maps&ibi=com.google.Maps&ius=comgooglemapsurl&isi=585027354
```

Please help me how can I get above-mentioned Location Info URL by Google API to get Location **(Lat, Lng)** through Google Map shared location Url from any device **(IOS, WebAPP, Specifically Android).**

Comment: Does this code still work? I studiwd webview behaviour and Google has added redirection by parameter tohttps://consent.google.com/mcontinue=https://www.google.com/maps/place/...

Comment: @ReijoKorhonen don't know bro but it's most generic so it should work i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems now (in 2019) there is no separate API or service for expanding shared location URL from Google Maps, but you can use workaround based on that trick: Google server can do it via Google Maps web interface.

**TLDR;**

You don't need [expand API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expand). For example, if

`https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3`

URL typed in the web browser on PC (e.g. FireFox) than that URL was expanded and the marker was shown. And during that you can see in address field "partially expanded" URL like:

`https://www.google.com/maps/place//data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x391904e4af9b1e35:0xee6f3c848c9e5341?utm_source=mstt_1`

which in 1-2 sec changed (redirected to) by "full expanded" URL with lat/lng coordinates like:

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/Siddique+Trade+Center/@31.5313297,74.3504459,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x391904e4af9b1e35:0xee6f3c848c9e5341!8m2!3d31.5313297!4d74.3526346`.

So you can use [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) to do the same and get "full expanded" from it (e.g. in [`public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) of [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient)). NB: it's necessary to skip first "partially expanded" URL.

The other issue: `WebView` converts shortened URL like `https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3` into Intent for Google Maps Application and "partially expanded" URL
`https://www.google.com/maps/place//data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x391904e4af9b1e35:0xee6f3c848c9e5341?utm_source=mstt_1` never be loaded. Actually it's enough if you need just show marker. But if you need coordinates this issue can be solved if you open shortened URL `https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3` by [`HttpUrlConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) and get redirected "partially expanded" URL via [`HttpUrlConnection.getURL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection#getURL()) or via `Location` Header field after connection opened and [`HttpUrlConnection.getInputStream()` called](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#handling-network-sign-on). Actually, if you load all response from `HttpUrlConnection` input stream as `String` - you can find desired lat/lng coordinates within it by `https://www.google.com/maps/preview/place` tag. Something  like:

`...
[[[1,42]\n]\n,0,null,0,47]\n]\n,null,\"Suit 706 Siddiq Trade Center, Main Blvd Gulberg, Block H Gulberg III, Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan\",null,null,\"https://www.google.com/maps/preview/place/Siddique+Trade+Center,+Suit+706+Siddiq+Trade+Center,+Main+Blvd+Gulberg,+Block+H+Gulberg+III,+Lahore,+Punjab,+Pakistan/@31.5313297,74.3526346,3401a,13.1y/data\\u003d!4m2!3m1!1s0x391904e4af9b1e35:0xee6f3c848c9e5341\",1,null,null,null,null,null,
...`

for your shortened URL opened via `HttpUrlConnection`. IMHO better (but slightly slower) way is to pass "partially expanded" URL received from [`HttpUrlConnection.getURL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection#getURL()) into `WebView` and get "full expanded" URL from its address line. So, with full source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // configure WebView
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "");   // reset default User-Agent
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // skip non-"ful expanded" urls
                if (isUrlFullExpanded(url)) {
                    // extract lat/lng coordinates from "full expanded" URL String
                    LatLng latLng = getLatLngFromExpandedUrl(url);
                    // just show marker with extracted coordinates for test
                    onLatLngReceived(latLng);
                }
            }
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // start get LatLng from URL coordinates task    
        new GetLocationURL().execute(new String[] {"https://maps.app.goo.gl/eEhh3"});
    }


    private LatLng getLatLngFromExpandedUrl(String url) {
        final String beginMarker = "/@";
        final String endMarker = "/";
        final int ixCoordsStart = url.indexOf(beginMarker) + beginMarker.length();
        final int ixCoordsEnd = url.indexOf(endMarker, ixCoordsStart);
        String coordinatesString = url.substring(ixCoordsStart, ixCoordsEnd);

        LatLng latLng = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(coordinatesString)) {
            String[] coords = coordinatesString.split(",");
            if (coords.length >= 2) {
                latLng = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(coords[0]), Float.parseFloat(coords[1]));
            }
        }
        return latLng;
    }


    private boolean isUrlFullExpanded(String url) {
        return url.indexOf("place/") > -1 && url.indexOf("place//") == -1 && url.indexOf("/@") > -1;
    }


    private void onLatLngReceived(LatLng latLng) {
        if (mGoogleMap != null && latLng != null) {
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }

    private class GetLocationURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String locationUrl = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            // you can analyze response code
            //int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder responseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseStringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            // use commented code below if you want to get coordinates directly from HttpURLConnection response
            /*
            LatLng latLng = null;
            String responseString = responseStringBuilder.toString();
            String pattern = "\\\"https://www.google.com/maps/preview/place";
            int ixPlaceStart = responseString.indexOf(pattern);

            if (ixPlaceStart > -1) {
                int ixCoordsStart = responseString.indexOf("@", ixPlaceStart) + 1;
                int ixCoordsEnd = responseString.indexOf("/", ixCoordsStart);
                String coordinatesString = responseString.substring(ixCoordsStart, ixCoordsEnd);
                String[] coords = coordinatesString.split(",");
                // latLng - coordinates from URL
                latLng = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(coords[0]), Float.parseFloat(coords[1]));
            }
            */

            locationUrl = connection.getURL().toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return locationUrl;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // pass redirected "partially expandeded" URL to WebView
            mWebView.loadUrl(result);
        }
    }
}
```

and `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<YOUR_PACKAGE>.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can get something like this:

[image: Marker from expanded URL]

NB! Described behavior can be changed by Google at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your answer.

Comment: @You're welcome, but remember - things can be changed by Google any time.

Comment: I am receiving this URL `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&pcampaignid=fdl_short&url=https://www.google.com/maps/place//data%3D!4m2!3m1!1s0x15c3d01fb1137e59:0xe059579737b118db?utm_source%3Dmstt_1` instead of location URL through 'HttpUrlConnection' I think google scheme is changed

Comment: when I hit this URL in webView its always return me same URL.

Comment: @TanveerMunir What is your shorten URL for that case?

Comment: @TanveerMunir Please check `WebView` and `http.agent` (`System.setProperty("http.agent", "");`) settings. Your URL converts to `https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jeddah+Saudi+Arabia/@21.4498898,38.9309561,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x15c3d01fb1137e59:0xe059579737b118db!8m2!3d21.485811!4d39.1925048` on my side.

Comment: Thanks, the Async Task was very helpful modified to work in context.